# cakephp check password with profile update

Tags: cakephp

I am newbie to cake php and I have a problem.
    When a user updates his profile iam asking to enter his password.Now I dont know how to check it with the stored password.

```
 <?php echo $form->create('UserProfile', array('url' => array('action' => 'edit_profile', 'controller' => 'users'))); ?>

            <?php


            echo $form->input('nickname', array('label' => __('Display Name', true), 'class' => 'INPUT required'));          
            ?>
            <b>To save these settings, please enter your password</b><br /><br />
            <?php
            echo $form->input('repeat_password', array('label' => __('Password', true), 'class' => 'INPUT required','type'=>'password'));
            echo $form->input('private', array('label' => __('Set Profile Private', true), 'class' => 'INPUT required'));
            ?>
<!--            <div id="CityList">
                <?php
//                echo $form->input('city', array('id' => 'citySelect', 'name' => 'data[UserProfile][city]', 'empty' => __('Please select city', true), 'label' => __('City', true), 'class' => 'INPUT required'));
                ?>
            </div> -->


            <?php echo $form->submit(__('Submit', true), array('class' => 'save_btn')) ?>`
>
```

In My model i have applied the following validation on repeat password.

```
    'repeat_password' => array(
                array('rule' => 'check_repeatPassword'),
                array('rule' => 'notempty', 'message' => __('Required', true), 'require' => true),
                array('rule' => 'alphaNumeric', 'allowEmpty' => true, 'message' => __('Password must only contain letters and numbers.', true)),
                array('rule' => array('minLength', 6), 'allowEmpty' => true,
                    'message' => __('Password must be at least 6 characters long.', true)),
                array('rule' => array('maxLength', 16), 'allowEmpty' => true,
                    'message' => __('Password must be at most 16 characters long.', true))
            ),
     function check_repeatPassword($data) {
        $repeatPassword = $data['repeat_passowrd'];

        $passwordExists = $this->find('count', array('conditions' => array('User.repeat_password' => $repeatPassword)));
        if ($passwordExists == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In My Controller I have made the following edit profile method.

```
     function edit_profile() {

        $this->loadModel('UserProfile');
        $user = $this->_authenticate_user();

        $id = $user['account_num'];


        if (!empty($this->data)) {

            $this->data['UserProfile']['account_name'] = $id;

            unset($this->data['UserProfile']['country']);
            unset($this->data['UserProfile']['city']);

            if ($this->UserProfile->save($this->data)) {
                $userInfo = $this->User->getUserInfo($id);

                $this->User->reassign_session($userInfo);

                $this->flashMessage(__('Your Profile has been Updated successfully', true), 'Sucmessage');


                //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'profile'));
            } else {
                $this->flashMessage(__('Your Profile has not been updated. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        }
        if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data = $this->UserProfile->read(null, $id);
        }

//        $this->loadModel('Country');
//        $countries = $this->Country->find('list');
//        $this->set('countries', $countries);


        $this->loadModel('Nationality');
        $nationalities = $this->Nationality->find('list', array('fields' => array('name', 'name')));
        $this->set('nationalities', $nationalities);

        $this->pageTitle = __('Edit My Profile', true);
    }

Kindly help me how to do this.Thankssssss in advance
```

Comment: You can use the [Passwordable](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/) behavior and the option `"current" => true`. This would do the same thing, but as a safe implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are not storing passwords in plain text

I cannot avoid seeing this and being amazed:

```
$passwordExists = $this->find('count', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.repeat_password' => $repeatPassword
    )
));
```

Please, please confirm that you aren't storing user passwords in plain text, and if you are stop doing so *immediately* and execute the following sql:

```
ALTER TABLE users DROP repeat_password;
```

### Compare a hash with a hash

In the db, you should have the user's existing password stored as a one-way-hash. Assuming that's the case, to verify that the user entered their existing account password - just hash what they provided [in the same way the Auth component does](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L747), and compare to the db:

```
function check_repeatPassword($data) {
    $userId = $this->data['UserProfile']['account_name']; // from the question

    $userInput = current($data);
    $hashedUserInput = Security::hash($userInput, null, true);

    return $this->find('count', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'password' => $hashedUserInput,
            'id' => $userId
        )
    ));
}
```

This will confirm that the password the user entered, is the same as the one already in the db for that user.

Comment: thanks for reply sir.but now on inserting check_repeatPassword() it gives me server error.when i remove this function then its ok.

Comment: iam not storing the repeat password.I just check it with the stored password to ensure that its the right person to update.

Comment: i have fixed the error.Now when i enter empty password it still updates the profile.It gives no error

Comment: Thank you very much sir.The problem is still here and need to google as iam not getting help here.

Comment: thankss.its done finally.the error was in $this->find.its basically $this->User->find.